# add css to an element with exisiting css

Tags: javascript, css

if I have an html element with predefined css style

```
<h1 style="color:blue;">This is a header</h1>
```

Now if I want to add a new style called `text-align:center` to h1 element.

How can I add a new style attribute to the end of the style attribute without overwrite the existing style?

So the result will look something like

```
<h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center">This is a header</h1>
```

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question.  Just add a semi-colon after `text-align: center`, though I'm not even sure thats required.

Comment: Try to add a class instead.

Comment: `h1Element.style.textAlign = "center";`

Comment: Yes, use a stylesheet and class names.

Comment: That would be referred to as a Cascading Style Sheet. It is an external document that defines styles for any number of elements on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *three* methods of doing this:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j9JbT/2/)

**1 - set element style property** - on the fly JavaScript styling, however arguably breaks [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript_and_PHP)

HTML:

```
<h1 id="headerExample1" style="color:blue;">This is a header</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ex1 = document.getElementById('headerExample1');

if (someLogic) {
    ex1.style.textAlign = "center";
}
```

**2 - set the style attribute** - this is the dirtiest of the three but does give you an idea of how you can access/change the `style` property directly using JavaScript

HTML:

```
<h1 id="headerExample2" style="color:blue;">This is a header</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ex2 = document.getElementById('headerExample2');

if (someLogic) {
    ex2.setAttribute('style', ex2.getAttribute('style') + ";text-align:center");
}
```

**3 - CSS and classes** - this is the cleanest way to style the header with regard to [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

HTML:

```
<h1 id="headerExample3">This is a header</h1>
```

CSS:

```css
#headerExample3 {color:blue;}
.centered {text-align:center;}
```

​
JavaScript:

```css
var ex3 = document.getElementById('headerExample3');

if (someLogic) {
    ex3.className = "centered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline styles is a bad idea because it is difficult to override them and maintaining separation of content and layout is important in web development.

Best to use a stylesheet:

```
h1 {
    color:blue;
    text-align:center
}
```

with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1').style.textAlign="center";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:
    document.getElementById("h1id").style.textAlign = "center";

Replace the h1id above with the id you will provide in the html.